# HtmlTags in iTextSharp not working when converting html to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

For some reason I can´t seem to apply styles on my htmlElements.  I created a style bundle for testing purposes but the style is not aplied on each div element.  Can anyone spot out what I´m doing wrong?

```
try
{
    // set the file name
    string file = "C:/MyPdf.pdf";

    // create a pdf document
    Document document = new Document();

    // set the page size, set the orientation
    document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);

    // create a writer instance
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create));

    // open the document
    document.Open();

    // THIS STYLE IS SET FOR TESTING PURPOSES
    StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
    styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.BGCOLOR, "#ff0000");

    // html pagina inlezen
    string htmlText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\afl.html");

    // html pagina parsen in een arraylist van IElements
    List<IElement> htmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), styles);

    // add the IElements to the document
    for (int i = 0; i < htmlElements.Count; i++)
    {
        // cast the element
        IElement htmlElement = ((IElement)htmlElements[i]);
        document.Add(htmlElement);
    }

    // close the document
    document.Close();

    // open the pdf document
    //Process.Start(file);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var derp = ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTMLWorker isn't actively being maintained anymore and instead you are encouraged to use the XMLWorker.

That said, you'll find that neither support background colors on most tags except possibly table-based tags. The reason behind this is that the PDF spec itself doesn't support background colors. To achieve this iText would need to either use complex annotations or draw shapes behind the text.

See [this link for the current XMLWorker documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html), click the CSS Support in the left nav to see various properties supported.

Your code itself is correct and valid, its just a non-supported property that doesn't throw any errors.